# Commentary as answers

Tags: discussion

For this [4 year old question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7176/what-is-the-purpose-of-boiling-wort) that bubbled up recently...

Look at the answer from barking Pete.  Is this an acceptable answer in the SE format.  I flagged it during review, but I'll stop doing so if the homebrewing SE culture goes against that grain.  I only ask here because one of our moderators commented on the post.  Just don't want to be annoying when I am asked to review things like this.

My question is: Am I misinterpreting or over interpreting the spirit of SE Q&A format?

Answer (score 3):

I think you were correct, it was commentary not an answer and as such was moved into the comments section.